# Multidimensional array in for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to understand how to convert this script into a multidimensional array. I've got as far as the code below. It builds an array of the RGB colour string.

I want my array to store the R G and B values as well on each loop alongside the full string.

What's the best method inside a **for** loop?

```
for($y = 0; $y < $size[1]; $y += $granularity){ 
    $thisColor = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y); 
    $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, $thisColor); 
    $red = round(round(($rgb['red'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
    $green = round(round(($rgb['green'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
    $blue = round(round(($rgb['blue'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
    $thisRGB = $red . $green . $blue;
    if(array_key_exists($thisRGB, $colors)){ 
        $colors[$thisRGB]++; 
    }else{ 
        $colors[$thisRGB] = 1; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are not using any array in the code. My guess is that you haven't read the docs

Comment: Of course i am. $colors is an array.

Comment: Is this what you want `$thisRGB['RGB'] = $red . $green . $blue; $thisRGB['R']=$red; $thisRGB['G']=$green;$thisRGB['B']=$blue;`